# Android - replacing skipping frames with loading animation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a problem with skipping frames, on a real device which is around 90-110 frames, but on the emulator it's only 20-30.
I am having that problem because I have 5 fragments inside an activity, and every fragment has 15-30 buttons which are LinearLayouts, because I needed to have two pictures and TextView in one Button and that seemed a way to go.

That's the reason it is skipping frames and I need to wait a few seconds before it opens the activity.

That's not looking good and since I can't have less data in Fragments, I have decided to create loading animation.

But the problem is, whenever I create it ,following various tutorials on YouTube or StackOverflow, the loading animation appears only when the activity opens, and there's no use of it then.

Does anyone know the solution?

activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.Vjezbe">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_vjezbe" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.Vjezbe"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_vjezbe"
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Vježbe"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:background="#ffffff">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the **Branded Launch Theme** which has been added in the new Material Design Libraries of Android, for preventing cold starts of applications and can replace the loading animations. [There's a really good article here by Antonio Leiva.](http://antonioleiva.com/branded-launch-screen/)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a layout in your XML (for example a `RelativeLayout` with background color and a spinner) that takes all the screen size. And when you have finished loading the fragments, set that layout's visibility to `Gone`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Android, can you walk me trough step by step? I create new layout resource file with RelativeLayout as a root element? Then set the background color and put the progress bar in it? Or some custom spinner? Then what?

Comment: Post the XML of your Activity

Comment: Its up in the first post